# HBase local cluster failed to startup after shutdown in Java client

Tags: java, spring, maven, hadoop, hbase

I have a Maven project compiled with Java 7 uses Spring IoC that suppose to test the use in hbase-client jar.

The dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a test (using JUnit) that creates a local cluster, create a table and load some data, then client is connecting to cluster, execute lookup and perform shutdown to the cluster, then tries to startup the cluster again to check the client's re-connection mechanism.

The problem is, that during the startup of the cluster after being shutdown, it gets an exception, that after long researching, looks like the shutdown process hasn't completed successfully.

Any help to figure out how to shutdown properly the cluster would be great.

The code context:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestHBaseUserOfflineReconnection
{
    @Value("${userTableName}")
    private static String userTableName = "TestTable";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hbaseUserOfflineReconnectDao")
    private UserDao userOfflineReconnectDao;

    @Autowired
    private DemographicBenchmark benchmark;

    private Table htable;

    private static LocalHBaseCluster hbaseCluster;

    private static MiniZooKeeperCluster zooKeeperCluster;

    private static Configuration configuration;

    static Connection conn = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        // delete the default local folder for that HBase stores its files
        String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("/tmp/hbase-" + userName));
        initHbase();
    }

    public static void initHbase() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        zooKeeperCluster = new MiniZooKeeperCluster(configuration);
        zooKeeperCluster.setDefaultClientPort(2181);
        zooKeeperCluster.startup(new File("target/zookeepr-" + System.currentTimeMillis()));

        hbaseCluster = new LocalHBaseCluster(configuration, 1);
        hbaseCluster.startup();
    }

    @Before
    public void initeHTable() throws IOException
    {
        configuration.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());

        conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);

        HTableDescriptor table = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(userTableName));

        table.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf"));

        conn.getAdmin().createTable(table);

        htable = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf(userTableName));
    }

    public static void shutdown() throws IOException
    {
        hbaseCluster.shutdown();
        hbaseCluster.waitOnMaster(0);
        zooKeeperCluster.shutdown();
    }

@Test
    public void testHBaseReconnection() throws IOException, TkException, InterruptedException
    {
      // do some lookups with the client, and all goes well..

      shutdown();
      initHbase(); // HERE's I GET THE EXCEPTION

      // some more code...
      shutdown(); // after test finished, closing the cluster
    }
}
```

The exception I get:

> ERROR 2016-07-13 16:48:03,849
>   [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=4,queue=1,port=46727]
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices: Region server
>   localhost,44545,1468417682471 reported a fatal error: ABORTING region
>   server localhost,44545,1468417682471: Unhandled: Region server startup
>   failed Cause: java.io.IOException: Region server startup failed   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.convertThrowableToIOE(HRegionServer.java:2827)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1317)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:852)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsException: Metrics source
>   RegionServer,sub=Server already exists!   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.newSourceName(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.sourceName(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl.(BaseSourceImpl.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceImpl.(MetricsRegionServerSourceImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceImpl.(MetricsRegionServerSourceImpl.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.createServer(MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServer.(MetricsRegionServer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1301)
>
> ... 2 more

Comment: Why do you want to run HBase cluster two times?  It's not usual behavior for HBase even for tests. Why not to run HBase only once, test all you want and finally shutdown it?

Comment: Because the test is about to check that my re-connection mechanism works, even if the cluster becomes unavailable and then available again..and my client won't lose connection.